# Backup and restore app data via adb

Tags: adb, backup, restore

I have a app installed on my old phone with a lot of settings and data that I want to transfer to my new phone. So I tried using `adb backup`:

```
$ sudo adb backup -f org.secuso.privacyfriendlynotes.ab -apk
org.secuso.privacyfriendlynotes
WARNING: adb backup is deprecated and may be removed in a future release
Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation...
```

Which worked fine:

```
$ ls -la
...
-rw-r-----.  1 root   root   5057212 Jul 16 10:59 org.secuso.privacyfriendlynotes.ab
```

But then to import the data on my new phone, I tried using `adb restore`:

```
sudo adb restore org.secuso.privacyfriendlynotes.ab
WARNING: adb restore is deprecated and may be removed in a future release
Now unlock your device and confirm the restore operation.
```

I unlocked and confirmed and the phone said "Restore starting..." and then "Restore ended", so everything seem fine. But the data was not restored.

Comparing `/data/data/org.secuso.privacyfriendlynotes` on both phones clearly shows that my data wasn't restored at all.

I realize that `abd backup` and `adb restore` are deprecated. What are the alternatives now? (I don't want to use Titanium Backup etc. I only use open source software.)

Is there an official alternative way to do this?

Comment: If you would remove `-apk` from command-line you can directly see on the file size of the created .ab file if the backup was successful. If the backup failed the file size will just be a few bytes.

Comment: adb backup and restore of Secuso PF Notes works without problems on my devices. Just saved an image and restored it to a different device.

Comment: It was around 5MB in size which seems fairly accurate. My old device was an Android 9 device and the new one runs Android 11. I suspect that it stopped working on Android 11. But I dont know. Which version of Android were you using?

Comment: I was using Android 11 and 12, both Google Pixel devices. Don't forget that the backup also includes the APK files with is about 3.7MB of size (at least the version I found on apkpure).

Comment: Maybe a backup created on Android 9 can't be restored on Android 11.

Comment: https://github.com/BaltiApps/Migrate-OSS

Comment: Could be that ugly bug introduced around Android 7. If it's that, the work-around is easy: pull the APK separately (or extract it from the backup), and then precede the `adb restore` with an `adb install`. Restore should then succeed if the app was already installed before. My little tool [Adebar](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar) has some scripts for those tasks in its `tools/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I could think of was a combination of `adb pull`, `adb push`, `restorecon` and `chown`:

```
APP_ID="org.secuso.privacyfriendlynotes"

# Backup (RUN WITH OLD PHONE CONNECTED)
adb pull "/data/data/${APP_ID}"

# Restore (RUN WITH NEW PHONE CONNECTED)
APP_OWNERSHIP=$(adb shell stat --format "%U:%G" "/data/data/${APP_ID}")
adb shell mv "/data/data/${APP_ID}" "/data/data/${APP_ID}_backup"
adb push "./${APP_ID}" "/data/data/${APP_ID}"
adb shell restorecon "/data/data/${APP_ID}"
adb shell chown -R "${APP_OWNERSHIP}" "/data/data/${APP_ID}"
#adb shell rm -rf "/data/data/${APP_ID}_backup"
```

It does require root though.